# How do I run my pycharm file in the command line using arguments from the user?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have created a fileSearch program in pycharm and I would like to run it in my command line using arguments from the user.

```
import os
from os.path import join

lookfor = "*insert file name*"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("*choose directory*"):
print("searching"), root
if lookfor in files:
    print "Found %s" % join(root, lookfor)
    break
```

I would like to run this in the command line using user inputs like:

```
C:\..\..> fileSearch.py --fileName --Directory
```

Comment: for arguments you may want to use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to run a script from the command line simply type [python path/to/script](http://pythoncentral.io/execute-python-script-file-shell/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can but you can write a first code that ask the directory and then launch your other code from this code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `argparse` for command input parameter parser with option. you can also use `sys.arv`. For more details you can go through [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.htmlhttp://).

```
import os
from os.path import join
# argparse is the python module for user command line parameter parser.
import argparse

# command input from the user with given option
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-fileName.', action='store',
                    dest='fileName',
                    help='Give the file Name')
parser.add_argument('-Directory', action='store',
                    dest='dir',
                    help='Give the Directory Name')

# parsing the parameter into results
results = parser.parse_args()

# lookfor = "*insert file name*"

# retrieve the store value from the command line input.
lookfor = results.fileName
dir = results.dir

# for root, dirs, files in os.walk("*choose directory*"):
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    print("searching"), root
    if lookfor in files:
        print("Found %s" % join(root, lookfor))
        break
```

**command line example:**

`python fileSearch.py -fileName filename.txt -Directory C:/MyProgram`

Comment: Additionally, if you'd like to run the program from PyCharm directly, you can modify run configurations and set parameters to `$Prompt$` - then a prompt window for parameters' input will appear every time you run script.

Answer (score 0):

For command line apps I like to use the `Click` package http://click.pocoo.org/5/

in your case it would be something like so.

```
# app.py
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('-f', '--filename', help='File name')
@click.option('-d', '--directory', help='Directory')
def run(filename, directory):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        print('Searching: {}'.format(root))
        if filename in files:
            print "Found %s" % join(root, filename)
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Then from the command line you can run

```
$ python app.py -f file.txt -d dirname
$ python app.py --filename=file.txt --directory=dirname
$ python app.py --help // prints your help text
```

Click has a ton of great features to build out robust CLI apps. Like I said it is my goto.